# Using "is" operator to compare two variable types in C#

Tags: c#, .net, types

I know that I can easily compare two variable types like this:

```
i.GetType() == i2.GetType())
```

Also, this kind of comparison works fine:

```
int i = 0;
if(i is int){}
```

So, why something like this does not work, and I get error that "i2 is trying to be used as a Type"?

```
int i = 0;
int i2 = 0;
if(i is i2.GetType()){}
```

Similar, such construction doesn't work:

> typeof(str.GetType())

Comment: `typeof(str.GetType())` would be the same as `typeof(Type)` which is unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: It doesn't work because it's expecting an actual compile-time type, and not a `System.Type`.  Are you actually asking how you can accomplish what you're after as opposed to why the language is defined as it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between a *compile time* type (using the type name, like `int`) and a *runtime variable* which holds information *about* a type (a variable of type `System.Type`, such as what's returned by `i2.GetType()`). You seem to be confusing those two.

If you want to see if a variable is of a particular type, and you know what that type is at *compile time*, use [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator).

```
if (i is int)
```

If you don't know the comparison type at compile time, but instead at runtime, you need to use `GetType`.

For just straight-up equality comparison:

```
if (i.GetType() == i2.GetType())
```

And for testing if `i` inherits/implements from whatever `i2` is

```
i2.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(i.GetType())
```

`is` only works when you know the type (and with newer features of c#, other aspects of the type's schema) at compile time.

Comment: @KirkWoll actually that's applicable to value types as well because they can implement interfaces

Comment: Yeah, the basic syntax is `knownType.IsAssignableFrom(testType)`, i.e. `typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(someType)`, so looks good as far as the OP's example goes.  Also, good point, Aluan.